# Mocha Webcomponents testing - ReferenceError: customElements is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, web-component, jsdom

I'm trying to do some very basic webcoponnets testing using typescript and mocha. I'm using jsdom to mock out the basic documents global, so I have `--require jsdom-global/register` in my moch opts.

Here is my test:

```
import { assert } from "chai";

class WordCount extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

describe("simple test", () => {
    it("works", () => {
      customElements.define('word-count', WordCount, { extends: 'p' });
      assert.isOk(true);
    });
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: customElements is not defined
```

The latest version of JSDom (which I'm using) supports `customElements`. I think the issue boils down to `window.customElements` vs `customElements`. The former syntax works, but the code I'm trying to test uses the latter syntax. What's the difference?

Comment: side note: ``{ extends:'p' }`` will never work on Safari, [Apple decided not to implement Customized Built-In Elements](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5166).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **browser** context, there's not difference between [`window.customElements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/customElements) and `customElements` because `window` is the default namespace for the variables defined globally.

```
var my_var = 'foo"
console.log( window.my_var ) //foo
console.log( window.customElement === customElement )
```

The test JSDoc library is executed in the **Node.js** context, which is not a browser and therefore won't expose `window` as its global / default namespace.

However **JSDoc** exposes a *simulated* browser context through a `window` property. So you can use `window.customElements()` and there's no difference with the code you trying to test.

Comment: Thanks - so would it be considered good practice to change the code throughout to be `window.customElement` even though it's intended use in within the browser?

Comment: @Matthew I don't think it's a better practice to use window as it is implied in the browser.  You just have to know that it's optional in the browser context and mandatory in the nodejs context with JSDoc